# How to wrap iframe so it opens on click

Tags: html, css

I have an image which on hover displays the title of a video. I want to be able to click after hovering and have my iframe show up. I have been able to simply put the vimeo player in to pop up, but whenever I want to put the iframe in, it doesn't work. I understand I can't wrap it inside the  tag but I don't know another solution. Right now if you input the code, on hover the iframe appears. I want for it to not appear on hover, but appear when I click. Any help would be appreciated.

CODE:

```
<style>
.hoverfollow {
 position: fixed;
}

.hvrbox,
.hvrbox * {
box-sizing: border-box;

}

.hvrbox {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
width: 30%;
height: auto;

}

.hvrbox img {
max-width: 100%;

}

.hvrbox_background {
width: 400px;
height: 250px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_bottom {
display: block;

 }

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_top {
text-decoration: none;
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
color: #fff;
padding: 15px;
-moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
-ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_top,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_top {
opacity: 1;

}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text {
text-align: center;
font-family: "DIN";
font-size: 10px;
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 100%;
height: auto;

}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text_mobile {
font-size: 15px;
border-top: 1px solid rgb(179, 179, 179);
/* for old browsers */
border-top: 1px solid rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.7);
margin-top: 5px;
padding-top: 2px;
display: none;

}

.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-text_mobile {
display: block;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_image {
padding: 0;
background: none;

}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_slideup {
-moz-transform: translateY(100%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
-ms-transform: translateY(100%);
transform: translateY(100%);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_slideup,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_slideup {
-moz-transform: translateY(0);
-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
-ms-transform: translateY(0);
transform: translateY(0);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_slidedown {
-moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
-webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
-ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_slidedown,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_slidedown {
-moz-transform: translateY(0);
-webkit-transform: translateY(0);
-ms-transform: translateY(0);
transform: translateY(0);
}

 .hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_slideleft {
-moz-transform: translateX(100%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
-ms-transform: translateX(100%);
transform: translateX(100%);
  }

  .hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_slideleft,
  .hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_slideleft {
-moz-transform: translateX(0);
-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
-ms-transform: translateX(0);
transform: translateX(0);
  }

  .hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_slideright {
-moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
-ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
 transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_slideright,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_slideright {
-moz-transform: translateX(0);
-webkit-transform: translateX(0);
-ms-transform: translateX(0);
transform: translateX(0);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_scale {
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-transform: scale(0);
-webkit-transform: scale(0);
-ms-transform: scale(0);
transform: scale(0);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_scale,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_scale {
border-radius: 0%;
-moz-transform: scale(1);
-webkit-transform: scale(1);
-ms-transform: scale(1);
transform: scale(1);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_rotate {
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-transform: rotateZ(0);
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(0);
-ms-transform: rotateZ(0);
transform: rotateZ(0);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_rotate,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_rotate {
border-radius: 0%;
-moz-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
-ms-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_scale-rotate {
border-radius: 50%;
-moz-transform: scale(0) rotateZ(0);
-webkit-transform: scale(0) rotateZ(0);
-ms-transform: scale(0) rotateZ(0);
transform: scale(0) rotateZ(0);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_scale-rotate,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_scale-rotate {
border-radius: 0%;
-moz-transform: scale(1) rotateZ(360deg);
-webkit-transform: scale(1) rotateZ(360deg);
-ms-transform: scale(1) rotateZ(360deg);
transform: scale(1) rotateZ(360deg);
}

body,
p,
a,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
div {
font-family: "DIN", sans-serif !important;
margin: 0;
text-decoration: none;
}

header {
background: #009FDA none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.5);
padding: 5px 15px;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
overflow: hidden;
}

header img {
height: 50px;
float: left;
}

header h1 {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 26px;
line-height: 48px;
}

.content h1,
.content h2,
.content h3 {
  margin: 15px 0 0px 0;
}

.content {
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}

pre {
background: #F2F2F2 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
font-size: 15px;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 3px;
margin: 10px 0;
white-space: pre-wrap;
-ms-tab-size: 4;
-moz-tab-size: 4;
-o-tab-size: 4;
tab-size: 4;
}

footer {
background: #000;
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 13px;

}

footer a {
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover,
footer a:focus {
text-decoration: underline;
}

.align {
top: 5%;
left: 5%;

}

iframe {
width: 700px;
/* adjust to your needs */
max-width: 100%;
/* to make it responsive */
animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-duration: 4s;
}

#amaka {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin-top: 5%;
animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-duration: 4s;

}

  </style>

   <main>

      <a class="align" href="test">

    <div class="hvrbox align">

      <img id="amaka" src="http://www.noscht.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/amaka.png" alt="AMAKA" class="hvrbox-layer_bottom">

      <div class="hvrbox-layer_top">
       
     <div class="hvrbox-text">

      AMAKA QUEENETTE - "SUFFOCATE"</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the source attribute of your IFrame and only set it `onClick`

Give your IFrame a unique identifier so you can find it with `document.getElementById()`.

```
<iframe id='myIframe' frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="550" height="400">
```

The IFrame should then have a source. You can set the source for example like this:

```
 document.getElementById("myIframe").src = "https://yoursource.com"
```

Now add this code inside the `onClick` attribute to your element you want the user to click on.

```
onClick='document.getElementById("myIframe").src="https://yoursource.com"
```

So your full HTML could look like this:

```
<iframe id='myIframe' frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="550" height="400">
<p onClick="document.getElementById("myIframe").src="https://yoursource.com"">Click here</p>
```

Comment: Do I need to input an id? And what would I put for the source? I added the code into the element like you said but nothing happened.

Comment: Could you add your, for the question requiered HTML Code?

Comment: My original code is inputed above. Are you asking for the code I am trying now based off of your solution?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hoverfollow {
    position: fixed;
}

.hvrbox,
.hvrbox * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.hvrbox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;

}

.hvrbox img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.hvrbox_background {
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_bottom {
    display: block;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_top {
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_top,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_top {
    opacity: 1;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "DIN";
    font-size: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-text_mobile {
    font-size: 15px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(179, 179, 179);
    /* for old browsers */
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.7);
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    display: none;
}

.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-text_mobile {
    display: block;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_image {
    padding: 0;
    background: none;
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_slideup {
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_slideup,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_slideup {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_slidedown {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_slidedown,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_slidedown {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_slideleft {
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_slideleft,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_slideleft {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_slideright {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_slideright,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_slideright {
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_scale {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_scale,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_scale {
    border-radius: 0%;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_rotate {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(0);
    transform: rotateZ(0);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_rotate,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_rotate {
    border-radius: 0%;
    -moz-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
}

.hvrbox .hvrbox-layer_scale-rotate {
    border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-transform: scale(0) rotateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0) rotateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0) rotateZ(0);
    transform: scale(0) rotateZ(0);
}

.hvrbox:hover .hvrbox-layer_scale-rotate,
.hvrbox.active .hvrbox-layer_scale-rotate {
    border-radius: 0%;
    -moz-transform: scale(1) rotateZ(360deg);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotateZ(360deg);
    -ms-transform: scale(1) rotateZ(360deg);
    transform: scale(1) rotateZ(360deg);
}

body,
p,
a,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
div {
    font-family: "DIN", sans-serif !important;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    background: #009FDA none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.5);
    padding: 5px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

header img {
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}

header h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 48px;
}

.content h1,
.content h2,
.content h3 {
    margin: 15px 0 0px 0;
}

.content {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

pre {
    background: #F2F2F2 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    -ms-tab-size: 4;
    -moz-tab-size: 4;
    -o-tab-size: 4;
    tab-size: 4;
}

footer {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

footer a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover,
footer a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.align {
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
}

iframe {
    width: 700px;
    /* adjust to your needs */
    max-width: 100%;
    /* to make it responsive */
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

#amaka {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 4s;
}

#myIframe {}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="hvrbox align">
      <img id="amaka" src="http://www.noscht.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/amaka.png" alt="AMAKA" class="hvrbox-layer_bottom">
      <a href="#">
      <div onClick='document.getElementById("myIframe").src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/389137312"' class="hvrbox-layer_top"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="hvrbox-text">
      AMAKA QUEENETTE - "SUFFOCATE"</div>
    <iframe id="myIframe" onClick="https://player.vimeo.com/video/389137312" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: So, I tried your solution separately without my hoverboxes and it worked. However, it seems that with my hoverbox it really messes with the layout and positioning of the iframe. It seems to be stuck under the semi-transparent box. Not sure how to fix that now.